# minimum number of machine for overlapping jobs

Tags: java, c++, dynamic-programming

Given a list of overlapping jobs that need to be scheduled. Determine the minimum number of machines needed.

so for example, the input is: {{1,6}, {2, 3}, {4,5}}.

we can have two machines: M1 to work on {1, 6}. and M2 to work on {2, 3} and {4, 5}.

my initial take is to use a vector of stacks, each stack represent a machine. But that takes too much space. my other guess is to use dynamic programming...

any help?

Java or C++.

Comment: _"Java or C++"_ shows that you have done nothing yet. please show some research effort

Comment: I don't understand the problem description. What do the job numbers mean? What are the rules about which machines can work on what? Why would M2 work on two jobs and M1 on one? I also don't understand your initial take. Show us some code, please.

Comment: Sounds like an Operating Systems class homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, a job is defined by its start and end times, {a,b}.

{{7,8}, {2,11}, {7,8}, {1,7}, {2,3}, {2,7}, {1,9}}

Sort the jobs by their starting times.

{{1,7}, {1,9}, {2,11}, {2,3}, {2,7}, {7,8}, {7,8}}

When a job is due to start, there may be several machines free. WLOG, imagine that the machines have "rank", so that the highest-ranking of all the free machines takes the job. (If several jobs start at the same time, it doesn't matter which one the highest-ranking machine takes.)

Now we can see which jobs the highest-ranking machine takes, and remove them from the pool. Repeat with the next-highest-ranking machine, and so on until all jobs are spoken for.

{**{1,7}**, {1,9}, {2,11}, {2,3}, {2,7}, **{7,8}**, {7,8}}
{**{1,9}**, {2,11}, {2,3}, {2,7}, {7,8}}
{**{2,11}**, {2,3}, {2,7}, {7,8}}
{**{2,3}**, {2,7}, **{7,8}**}
{**{2,7}**}

In this case 5 machines are needed.